# NullPointerException getting hibernate session

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am trying to integrate Hibernate 5.2.12 into my Spring application but am getting a nullPointerException when get a session.

Here is the Hibernate configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class HibernateConfig {

@Bean
public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
    System.out.println("Session factory called!");
    LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
    sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(
            "com.app.persistence.model");
    sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());

    return sessionFactory;
}

@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {

    BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
    dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/appDatabase?useSSL=false");
    dataSource.setUsername("root");
    dataSource.setPassword("password");

    return dataSource;
}

@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager hibernateTransactionManager() {
    HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager
            = new HibernateTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory().getObject());

    return transactionManager;
}

private final Properties hibernateProperties() {
    Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
    hibernateProperties.setProperty(
            "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "");
    hibernateProperties.setProperty(
            "hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect");

    return hibernateProperties;
}
```

}

Here is the my util class where sessionFactory is @AutoWired

```
public class AppHibernateUtil {

private static final AppHibernateUtil instance = new AppHibernateUtil();

@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public static Session getSession() {

    return getInstance().sessionFactory.openSession();
}

private static AppHibernateUtil getInstance() {
    return instance;
}
```

}

Here's my attempted usage of a session

```
public static String getRoles() {

    System.out.println("Custom: getRoles() called");

    List<RoleEntity> roles = new ArrayList<>();

    try(Session session = AppHibernateUtil.getSession()){

        roles = session.createQuery("from RoleEntity").list();
    }

    return gson.toJson(roles.size());
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    System.out.println(getRoles());
}
```

The null exception is thrown here

```
return getInstance().sessionFactory.openSession();
```

This line never gets outputted at the console

```
System.out.println("Session factory called!");
```

If I ignore the AppHibernateUtil class by creating a test class which injects (or not) the sessionFactory. I get the same NPE

```
@Component
public class TestController {

private static Gson gson = new Gson();

@Autowired
private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public static String getRoles() {

    System.out.println("Custom: getRoles() called");

    List<RoleEntity> roles = new ArrayList<>();

    try(Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()){

        roles = session.createQuery("from RoleEntity").list();
    }

    return gson.toJson(roles.size());
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    System.out.println(getRoles());
}
}
```

Comment: Ditch your `AppHibernateUtil` is is flawed in multiple ways... Just inject the `SessionFactory` where you need it and call `getCurrentSession`. Don't use the utility class. Also `@Autowired` doesn't work on `static` fields only instance fields. Also you aren't using Spring to inject anything you are just calling a static method nothing more and nothing less, no spring involved there.

Comment: Is the spring context initialised when running a 'public static main' method?

Comment: Only when you construct the context, you aren't and hence nothing is being started.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is not in your hibernate configuration, but in your dependency injection.

You are creating manually singleton of AppHibernateUtil (you are calling `new AppHibernateUtil()`), let Spring do its job and annotate AppHibernateUtil with `@Component` (default scope of component is Singleton), then inject it into you class, where is your session needed.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the NPE is being thrown because the `sessionFactory` in the `getSession()` method is null.

This means that Spring is not injecting an instance of `SessionFactory`.

That may be because you've chosen to implemented the `AppHibernateUtil` as a singleton. I won't disgress into a discussion about that, except that's it's relevant to point out that Spring is based on dependency injection and using singletons goes against that approach.

If you want to keep using a singleton, you may have success with additional annotations on the `AppHibernateUtil` class:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.your.package.HibernateConfig")
public class AppHibernateUtil {
...
}
```

However, as described in the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Configuration.html), it would probably be best to refactor the `AppHibernateUtil` class so that it was not a singleton:

```
@Configuration
public class AppHibernateUtil {
    private final AppConfig appConfig;

    public AppHibernateUtil(AppConfig appConfig) {
         this.appConfig = appConfig;
     }
}
```